# Submit changed FormData in ASP.NET form to have normal behavior with ModelState and redirections

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, form-data

I'm developing a web app with APS.NET Core MVC (.NET 5.0). I have an entity (Service) that have a dynamic list of another entity (OpeningHours). So a service can have different opening hours, for example:

- From 08:00 to 20:00
- From 08:00 to 13:00 and from 17:00 to 20:00

You can set different time slots, as many as you want. I didn't know how to implement this case and looking for the solution I found [How to dynamically add items from different entities to lists in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487500/how-to-dynamically-add-items-from-different-entities-to-lists-in-asp-net-core-mv) and followed the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63571389/4600693) adapting it to my entities. Simplifying a bit, this would be the code:

**Models (or ViewModels):**

```
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<ServiceOpeningHours> OpeningHours { get; set; } = new List<ServiceOpeningHours>();
}

public class ServiceOpeningHours
{
    public TimeSpan From { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan To { get; set; }
}
```

**Create.cshtml (View):**

```
@model MyWebApp.Services.Models.Service

...

<form asp-action="Create" name="createForm" id="createForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Name</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
            <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Opening Hours</legend>
            <div id="openingHoursContainer">
                @foreach (ServiceOpeningHours item in Model.OpeningHours)
                {
                    <partial name="_OpeningHourEditor" manifest model="item" />
                }
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="addOpeningHourItem" type="button" value="Add Opening Hour" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

...

@section Scripts {
    $('#addOpeningHourItem').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Services/AddBlankOpeningHour',
            success: function (partialView) {
                $('#openingHoursContainer').append(partialView);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#submit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("Name", $('input[name="Name"]').val());
        formData.append("Description", $('input[name="Description"]').val());

        $("input[name='From']").each(function (i) {
            var from = $(this).val();
            formData.append("OpeningHours[" + i + "].From", from);
        });
        $("input[name='To']").each(function (i) {
            var to = $(this).val();
            formData.append("OpeningHours[" + i + "].To", to);
        });

        formData.append("__RequestVerificationToken", $('form[name="createForm"] input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Services/Create',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (returnValue) {
                console.log('Success: ' + returnValue);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**_OpeningHourEditor.cshtml (partial view for opening hour item):**

```
@model MyWebApp.Models.ServiceOpeningHours

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">From</label>
            <input asp-for="From" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="From" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">To</label>
            <input asp-for="To" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="To" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the javascript code a `FormData` is created and filled with all fields and the model successfully arrives at the `Create` action.

**ServiceController:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Service service)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Save data in data base...

        return this.RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(service);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddBlankOpeningHour()
{
    return PartialView("_OpeningHourEditor", new ServiceOpeningHours());
}
```

With this code, when the `Create` action returns the response, it reaches the `success` block of `$.ajax()`, but this does not cause the page to reload with the new data.

I think you shouldn't do it with AJAX. How should I make the call so that everything works normally? That is, if the `Name` or `Description` fields are not filled in, the `ModelState` error message should be displayed, and if all goes well it should be redirected to the `Index` action.

Comment: will you clarify-- do you still want to keep ajax submit?

Comment: I don't care how to send the data, with or without AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified the submit script to remove ajax and initially change the name of the input fields so that the list will be bound to the model properly.

```
$('#submit').click(function (event) {
   // initially prevent form submit
   event.preventDefault();
   
   // loop through all input with name From, and change their name with index
   $("input[name='From']").each(function (i) {
      $(this).attr("name", "OpeningHours[" + i + "].From");
   });
   
   // loop through all input with name To, and change their name with index
   $("input[name='To']").each(function (i) {
      $(this).attr("name", "OpeningHours[" + i + "].To");
   });
   
   // submit the form
   $("#createForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: if the model is not capturing the list `OpeningHours`.. looks like you need to include the partial view in your question, since the input fields there should have indexes in the html name attribute.

Comment: You are right, removing ```$('#submit').click()``` ```OpeningHours``` is not captured properly, because all input fields have the same name: ```From``` and ```To```. I'm going to edit the question with needed code.

Comment: Partial view and controller action added.

Comment: @Jon I updated the code, actually we could just rename the input fields so that they can be bound properly

Comment: I tested it but the form is not submited. I changed ```$("#createForm").submit();``` with ```document.getElementById('createForm').submit();``` and with this I get this error in the console: ```Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function```.

Comment: Ok, it is because ```submit``` ```input```'s ```id``` is ```submit``` too, changing this ```id``` works perferct! Thank you very much!!!