# ASP.Net Core: How do I update (change/add/remove) nested item objects (One-to-Many relationship)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, one-to-many

I have an .Net 5.x project with "MSCustomers" and "MSLocations".  There's a many-to-one of MSLocations to MSCustomers.

My "Edit" page correctly displays an "MSCustomer" record and the corresponding "MSLocations" fields.

**PROBLEM:**

"Edit" should allow me to modify or "remove" any MSLocation.  But when I save the record, none of the MSLocations are changed.

**MSCustomer.cs:**

```
public class MSCustomer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string EngagementType { get; set; }
    public string MSProjectNumber { get; set; }
    // EF Navigation
    public virtual ICollection<MSLocation> MSLocations { get; set; }
 }
```

**MSLocation.cs**

```
public class MSLocation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public int MSCustomerId { get; set; }  // FK
    // EF Navigation
    public MSCustomer MSCustomer { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit.cshtml.cs:**

```
public class EditModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public MSCustomer MSCustomer { get; set; }
    ...
    public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
    {          
        if (id == null)
            return NotFound();

        MSCustomer = ctx.MSCustomer
            .Include(location => location.MSLocations)
            .FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);

        return Page();  // This all works...
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string? submitButton)
    {
        ctx.Attach(MSCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;
        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("Index"); // Saves MSCustomer updates, but not MSLocations...
```

**Edit.cshtml.cs**

```
@page
@model HelloNestedFields.Pages.MSFRD.EditModel
@using HelloNestedFields.Models
...
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="MSCustomer.ID" />
    ...
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="min-width:140px">Address</th>
                <th style="min-width:140px">City</th>
                <th style="min-width:140px">State</th>
                <th style="min-width:140px">Zip</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (MSLocation loc in @Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations)
            {
                <tr id="row_@loc.ID">
                    <td><input asp-for="@loc.Address" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@loc.City" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@loc.State" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@loc.Zip" /></td>
                    <td><button onclick="removeField(@loc.ID);">Remove</button></td>
                </tr>
            }
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><button id="add_location_btn">Add Location</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    ...
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeField(element_id) {
        try {
          let row_id = "row_" + element_id;
          console.log("removeField, element_id=" + element_id + ", row_id=" + row_id + "...");
          let tr = document.getElementById(row_id);
          console.log("tr:", tr);
          tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
        debugger;
    };
</script>

}
```

**HelloNestedContext.cs**

```
public class HelloNestedContext : DbContext
{
    public HelloNestedContext(DbContextOptions<HelloNestedContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<HelloNestedFields.Models.MSCustomer> MSCustomers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HelloNestedFields.Models.MSLocation> MSLocations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MSCustomer>()
            .HasMany(d => d.MSLocations)
            .WithOne(c => c.MSCustomer)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.MSCustomerId);
    }
}
```

Q: What am I missing?

Q: What do I need to do so that *MSCustomers.MSLocations* updates are passed from the browser back to OnPostAsync(), and saved correctly?

I'm sure it's *POSSIBLE*.  But I haven't been able to find any documentation or sample code anywhere for modifying "nested item objects" in a "record object".

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

---

**Update:**

Razor pages don't seem to support binding to a "complex" object (with nested lists within a record).

So I tried Okan Karadag's excellent suggestion below - I split "MSLocations" into its own binding, then added it back to "MSCustomer" in the "POST" handler.  This got me *CLOSER* - at least now I'm now able to update nested fields.  But I'm still not able to add or remove MSLocations in my "Edit" page.

**New Edit.cshtml.cs**

```
[BindProperty]
public MSCustomer MSCustomer { get; set; }
[BindProperty]
public List<MSLocation> MSLocations { get; set; }
...

public IActionResult OnGet(int? id)
{          
    MSCustomer = ctx.MSCustomer
        .Include(location => location.MSLocations)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);
    MSLocations = new List<MSLocation>(MSCustomer.MSLocations);
   ...

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string? submitButton)
{
    MSCustomer.MSLocations = new List<MSLocation>(MSLocations);  // Update record with new
    ctx.Update(MSCustomer);
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
   ...
```

**New Edit.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    ...
    <table>
        ...
        <tbody id="mslocations_tbody">
            @for (int i=0; i < Model.MSLocations.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr id="row_@Model.MSLocations[i].ID">      
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].Address" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].City" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].State" /></td>
                    <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].Zip" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].ID" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.MSLocations[i].MSCustomerId" />
                        <button onclick="removeLocation(row_@Model.MSLocations[i].ID);">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onclick="addLocation();">Add Location</button>
</div>
```

**Current Status:**

- I can update top-level "MSCustomer" data fields OK.
- I can update existing "MSlocation" fields OK.
- I *CANNOT* add new or remove current MSLocation items.
- The "blocker" seems to be Razor bindings: communicating the "updated" MSLocations list from the Razor "Edit" page back to the C# "POST" action handler.

My next step will be to try this:

[How to dynamically add items from different entities to lists in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487500/how-to-dynamically-add-items-from-different-entities-to-lists-in-asp-net-core-mv)

It would be great if it worked.  It would be even *BETTER* if there were a simpler alternative that didn't involve Ajax calls..

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have attributes on your navigation properties unless you configure in code, `onmodelbuilding`?? `InversePropertyAttribute` on `MSCustomer` and  `MSLocations`

Comment: I have an OnModelCreating() method, and added it to my post.  Please let me know what - if anything - I'm missing.

Comment: Ok. But something is not right, you have `form method="POST"` but trying to `DELETE`. Check this - `ctx.Attach(MSCustomer).State = EntityState.Modified;` you assign `modified`. But to delete do - `Deleted`. But this is heresy to Delete on Post. Well, speaking of REST. Potencially in Razor pages it is ok,

Comment: I have a "record" (an MSCustomer).  The record has a list ("MSLocations").  Everything works fine in Edit.cshtml.cs > OnGet(); everything displays fine in the "Edit.cshtml" Razor page.  PROBLEM: None of the changes I made to any "MSLocation" item ever gets saved.  I can't even change an "Address" or a "City".  I haven't found anything in the MS Documentation or from a Google search that tells me why.  Q: How do I "change" a "nested item" in ASP.Net Core?  Or add a new item, or remove an existing item from the record's items list? Q: Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: you can use `context.Locations.RemoveRange.(locs) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK: my basic challenge was figuring out how to create a simple web form - in ASP.Net Core MVC - with a "master record" having "nested fields".

One "Razor page" where I could create and edit a schema like this:

```
* Customers
     int ID
     string Name
     List<Location> Locations

* Locations:
    int ID
    string Address
    string City
    string State
    string Zip
    int CustomerID
```

1. I started out creating my models:

   *Models\Customer.cs*

   ```
    public class Customer  {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public string EngagementType { get; set; }
        public string MSProjectNumber { get; set; }
        // EF Navigation
        public virtual ICollection<MSLocation> MSLocations { get; set; }
   ```

   *Models\MSLocation.cs*

   ```
    public class MSLocation {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }  // FK
        // EF Navigation
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
          <= Both Customer, MSLocation configured for EF navigation
   ```
2. Next, I configured my DBContext to support navigation:

   *Data\HelloNestedContext.cs*

   ```
    public class HelloNestedContext : DbContext {
        ...
        public DbSet<HelloNestedFields.Models.Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<HelloNestedFields.Models.MSLocation> MSLocations { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            ...
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .HasMany(d => d.MSLocations)
                .WithOne(c => c.Customer)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CustomerId);
          <= Configure "One::Many " relationship in DbContext
   ```
3. It's easy and efficient to use query master record and nested fields all-at-once:

   *Pages\MSFRD\Edit.cshtml.cs > OnGet()*

   ```
    Customer = ctx.Customers
        .Include(location => location.MSLocations)
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.ID == id);
          <= So far, so good: this all worked fine in the original "Departments/Courses/Course Auditors" example...
   ```
4. CHALLENGES:

   - PROBLEM #1: Razor pages don't support binding to nested subfields (e.g. "Customer.MSLocations")
   - SOLUTION: Declare the subfield(s) as its own model variable (e.g. "List MSLocations"), and bind separately from "master record"
   - PROBLEM #2: Merge updates to separate "MSLocations" back in to "Customer.MSLocations" when update submitted
   - SOLUTION:

     *Pages\MSFRD\Edit.cshtml.cs > OnPostAsync ()*

     ```
     ...
     Customer.MSLocations = new List<MSLocation>(MSLocations);
     ctx.Update(Customer);
     await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
       <= No problem: Fairly straightforward...
     ```
   - PROBLEM #3a: Add new subfields to "Customer.MSLocations"
   - SOLUTION:  Use JS to create new HTML elements; follow same id/attribute element attribute naming conventions as Razor uses

     *EXAMPLE:*

     ```
     <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_3__Address" name="MSLocations[3].Address" />
     <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_3__City" name="MSLocations[3].City" />
     ...
     ```

     *Pages\MSFRD\Edit.cshtml*

     ```
     function addLocation() {
         console.log("addLocation(), maxRow=" + maxRow + "...");
         //debugger;
         try {
           let markup =
            `<tr id="row_${maxRow}">
                <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__Address" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].Address" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__City" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].City" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__State" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].State" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__Zip" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].Zip" /></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__ID" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].ID"  value="0" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="MSLocations_${maxRow}__CustomerId" name="MSLocations[${maxRow}].CustomerId" value="@Model.Customer.ID" />
                    <button onclick="return removeLocation(row_${maxRow}, ${maxRow});">Remove</button>
                </td>
            </tr>`;
            //console.log("markup:", markup);
            let tbody = $("#mslocations_tbody");
            tbody.append(markup);
            ++maxRow;
     ```
   - PROBLEM #3b: Tracking current row#
   - SOLUTION: `<input type="hidden" id="MaxRow" value="@Model.MaxRow" />`
   - PROBLEM #4: Delete subfields

     - Simply updating the DB with "MSLocations" is *NOT* sufficient
     - To "delete" an entity, you *MUST* explicitly call "context.Remove(Item)"
   - SOLUTION:

     - Declare and bind model variable "public string DeletedLocations { get; set;}"
     - Initialize it to an empty JSON array ("[]})
     - Use JS to remove all "MSLocations...."  elements for that item from the HTML
     - The same JS function also saves the item being deleted to the "DeletedLocations" JSON array
     - Upon "Submit", deserialize "DeletedLocations" and call ""context.Remove()" on each item:

     *Pages\MSFRD\Edit.cshtml.cs > OnPostAsync ()*

     ```
     ...
     JArray deletedLocations = JArray.Parse(DeletedLocations);
     foreach (var jobject in deletedLocations) {
         MSLocation MSLocation = jobject.ToObject<MSLocation>();
         ctx.Remove(MSLocation);
     }
     ```

     - Following the "ctx.Remove()" loop, update "Customer" with all adds/modifies, and call "ctx.SaveChangesAsync()":

       ```
       // Remove any deleted locations from DB
       JArray deletedLocations = JArray.Parse(DeletedLocations);
       foreach (var jobject in deletedLocations) {
           MSLocation MSLocation = jobject.ToObject<MSLocation>();
           ctx.Remove(MSLocation);
       }

       // Associate MSLocations modifications/updates with Customer record
       Customer.MSLocations = new List<MSLocation>(MSLocations);
       ctx.Update(Customer);

       // Update DB
       await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
       ```

- Key benefits:

  a. MINIMIZE the #/round trips to the DB

  b. MINIMIZE the amount of SQL-level data for each round trip

Answer (score 3):

When sending data, it should be `customer.Locations[0].City : "foo"` `customer.Locations[1].City : "bar"`, You should post as Locations[index]. you can look passed data in network tab at browser.

Solution 1 (with `for`)

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MSCustomer.Locations.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr id="row_@loc.ID">
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.Locations[i].Address" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.Locations[i].City" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.Locations[i].State" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.Locations[i].Zip" /></td>
        <td><button onclick="removeField(@loc.ID);">Remove</button></td>
     </tr>
}
```

solution 2 (with `foreach`)

```
@foreach (MSLocation loc in @Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations)
{
    <tr id="row_@loc.ID">
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations[loc.Id].Address" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations[loc.Id].City" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations[loc.Id].State" /></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.MSCustomer.MSLocations[loc.Id].Zip" /></td>
        <td><button onclick="removeField(@loc.ID);">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you - trying it now.  NOTE: the *ONLY* [BindProperty] in the model is `public MSCustomer MSCustomer { get; set; }`.  MSLocations is a "nested list" *WITHIN* the MSCustomer object.  I tried making a separate binding for MSLocations, but it didn't work.  ALSO: I can't use MSLocations with a for() loop: `CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type Icollection<MSLocation>`

Comment: Oh I'm understand, have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you: your help is valuable.  Please see my updates above.  I was able to work around the index error.  I think the basic issue is that *I CANNOT UPDATE BOTH "MSCustomer" (the master record) AND "MSLocations" (the nested items list) AT THE SAME TIME*.  It seems that I need to have one binding for "MSCustomer", and a different, separate binding for "List<MSLocations>".  CURRENT PROBLEM: I can't seem to "overwrite" MSLocations. It keeps "appending" instead...